# Having a grid with a calendar as columns

Tags: jquery

I need a jquery plugin or a way to build with jQuery a grid that has tasks as lines and days (navigable by week) as columns, in order to enter somme (task,date) values. Can someone help me ?

Comment: What I am looking for exactly, is a jquery plugin to build a timesheet

Answer (score 0):

[Home Page](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/)

[Demo](http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html)

This - one of the best

EDITED:

Then try to look at this plugin: [image: jMonthCalendar].

Here is project [home page](http://www.bytecyclist.com/projects/jmonthcalendar/).

Comment: Thank you, but I need to have (predefined) tasks as rows, not hours.